# Eloquient with relation not working with find

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am new to laravel. I am facing a very weird problem. I have a model comment which is related to User model in laravel.
The Relationships are defined as such

```
//App\User model
    public function comments()
    {
            return  $this->hasMany('App\comment');
    }
```

And

```
//App\Comment model
    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

now when i am fetching user and comment s using find and with it is returning data for all the users in the table. My code is like this: `App\User::find(1)->with('comments')->get();` Can some one tell me what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$comments=App\User::whereId(1)->comments->get();
```

This should load every comment associated with user with ID 1

Comment: ya I am already able to get it by using where.  but find does not work.

Answer (score 0):

//App\User model

```
public function comments() {
    return  $this->hasMany('App\comment','user_id','id');
}
```

//In your controller

```
use App\User;
$comment = User::where('id',2)->comments->get();
```

//I hope It's work for you!